# Не могу открыть php файл с dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

Выдает ошибку:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Dompdf\mb_internal_encoding() in C:\OpenServer\domains\Train\php\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php:305 Stack trace: #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\Train\php\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php(279): Dompdf\Dompdf->setPhpConfig() #1 C:\OpenServer\domains\Train\php\index.php(12): Dompdf\Dompdf->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\domains\Train\php\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php on line 305

код в 305 строке:

```
$this->mbstringEncoding = mb_internal_encoding();
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Comment: модуль `mb_string` проверьте что включен в пхп

Comment: а как его включить?

Comment: в конфиге пхп найдите строку